# How to use flexbox with Bootstrap alpha v6

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

With bootstrap alpha v4 there was the option to enable the use of flexbox within the file _variables.scss.

All we had to do was set `enable-flex:  false !default;` . to `enable-flex:  true !default;`

However I can't find the option to enable flexbox anywhere within the file _variables.scss after downloading the source files of Bootstrap alpha v6.

Any idea where we can enable flexbox and possible give me a simple example of how to use/implement it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex is used by default in v6, so there is no need to enable it (same you can't disable it). Read more at: https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/01/06/bootstrap-4-alpha-6/

Comment: Thank you,, that explains it all!